# OpenCV camera preview orientation issue

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I am developing an document scanner. I done this with things like detection, capture, save everything. I have a problem with the camera view screen. It is working fine in landscape mode but I want it in portrait orientation.

Also did that and doing all image processing operation perfectly. But it restart the app after some time in portrait mode. Can someone help me why its restarting app?

**Activity**

```
public class OpenCvCamera extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2, View.OnClickListener, FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {


// Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");
}



private Mat mRgba;
private Mat mIntermediateMat;
private Mat mGray;
private Mat mRgbaT;
private Button btnCapture;
private org.opencv.core.Rect mBoundingRect;
private static final String FILE_LOCATION= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/DocumentScan/";

private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {

    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                Log.i("TAG", "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            }
            break;
            default: {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
};



@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_2_0,
                this, mLoaderCallback);
    } else {
        mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cam);
    mOpenCvCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.java_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    btnCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
            File imgFolder = new File(FILE_LOCATION);
            imgFolder.mkdir();
            File image = new File(imgFolder, "Scan" + timestamp + ".jpg");
            String fileName = FILE_LOCATION +
                    "/Scan" + timestamp + ".jpg";
            Toast.makeText(OpenCvCamera.this, image + " saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Mat cropped = mRgbaT.submat( mBoundingRect );
            Imgcodecs.imwrite(fileName, cropped);

        }
    }) ;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView!=null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

public native Rect doWithMat(long matAddrGr, long matAddrRgba);

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    Log.d("Width", width + "\t" + height);
    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mIntermediateMat = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mGray = new Mat(height, width, CV_8UC1);
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    mRgba.release();
    mGray.release();
    mIntermediateMat.release();
}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    mGray = inputFrame.gray();
    mRgbaT = mRgba.t();
    Core.flip(mRgba.t(), mRgbaT, 1);
    Imgproc.resize(mRgbaT, mRgbaT, mRgba.size());
    mBoundingRect = doWithMat(mGray.getNativeObjAddr(), mRgbaT.getNativeObjAddr());


    return mRgbaT;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Study Android [Activity life cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

By using onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() you can get your data after change in orientation

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);


    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

> for checking after orientation change put this inside your onCreate()

```
// Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
        mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
    } else {
        // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
    }
```

> Or you can implement  onRestoreInstanceState()

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);


// Restore state members from saved instance
mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
```

}